# Use Realm for filtering and sorting nearby locations

Tags: android, location, realm

I want to query a realm db for nearby locations. The latitude and longitude informations are saved in the database. When I generate a bounding box, then I can just query all stations within the bounding box. I know that it isn't a radius, because I'm using a bounding box.

So I have a `RealmResult` with all locations in the area. I want to keep it as a `RealmResult` to benefit from the auto updating objects.

How can I sort the locations by distance to my current location? Only the locations and latitudes of the location are persisted and sortable.

Additionally it would be great if I could add an additional filter for the distance, so all locations are within the radius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm currently doesn't support geospatial queries, but we have an issue tracking it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1772

So I am afraid you are a bit out of luck doing it through the Realm API, but you might consider looking into something like GeoHash: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash. It is a representation of location using a bitstring and distance can be approximated comparing prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

[RealmGeoQueries](https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries) made it easy to do findNearby and findInRegion on iOS

Answer (score 0):

[Realm-js v12](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/releases/tag/v12.0.0) has introduced support for geospatial queries.

- The queries can be used to filter objects whose points lie within a certain area following spherical geometry, using the geoWithin operator in the query string to Results.filtered().
- The following shapes are supported in geospatial queries: circle (GeoCircle type, defined by its center and radius in radians), box (GeoBox type, defined by its bottom left and upper right corners) and polygon (GeoPolygon type, defined by its vertices).
- Additionally, two new functions have been added, kmToRadians() and miToRadians(), that can be used to convert kilometers and miles to radians respectively, simplifying conversion of a circle's radius.

```js
import Realm, {
  ObjectSchema,
  GeoCircle,
  CanonicalGeoPoint,
  GeoPosition,
  kmToRadians,
} from "realm";

// Example of a user-defined point class that can be queried using geospatial queries
class MyGeoPoint extends Realm.Object implements CanonicalGeoPoint {
  coordinates!: GeoPosition;
  type = "Point" as const;

  static schema: ObjectSchema = {
    name: "MyGeoPoint",
    embedded: true,
    properties: {
      type: "string",
      coordinates: "double[]",
    },
  };
}

class PointOfInterest extends Realm.Object {
  name!: string;
  location!: MyGeoPoint;

  static schema: ObjectSchema = {
    name: "PointOfInterest",
    properties: {
      name: "string",
      location: "MyGeoPoint",
    },
  };
}

realm.write(() => {
  realm.create(PointOfInterest, {
    name: "Copenhagen",
    location: {
      coordinates: [12.558892784045568, 55.66717839648401],
      type: "Point",
    } as MyGeoPoint
  });
  realm.create(PointOfInterest, {
    name: "New York",
    location: {
      coordinates: [-73.92474936213434, 40.700090994927415],
      type: "Point",
    } as MyGeoPoint
  });
});

const pois = realm.objects(PointOfInterest);

const berlinCoordinates: GeoPoint = [13.397255909303222, 52.51174463251085];
const radius = kmToRadians(500); //500 km = 0.0783932519 rad

// Circle with a radius of 500kms centered in Berlin
const circleShape: GeoCircle = {
  center: berlinCoordinates,
  distance: radius,
};

// All points of interest in a 500kms radius from Berlin
let result = pois.filtered("location geoWithin $0", circleShape);

// Equivalent string query without arguments
result = pois.filtered("location geoWithin geoCircle([13.397255909303222, 52.51174463251085], 0.0783932519)");
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is, while storing the data in Realm you can store a value called 'Distance from user' or something like that.. you can get this value by calculating the distance between the users lat,lon and the objects lat,lon.

Then you can sort your data using this value 'Distance from user' in descending or ascending order, which is very easy in Realm. Or you could use the comparer API in Realm to get the objects that are a particular distance from the user.

Comment: what if the user moves to another location? will the stored distances be valid?

Comment: No Since the user's location will change, the distance from object would change too, however since Realm is easy to update you can simple re-calculate that particular field, Maybe update the results every time the user moves a specific amount.?  I have been stuck with the same issue, and have not been able to find a better solution.

Comment: I have user same issue and user location is variable and thousands of entries in the database would you suggest an alternative solution?